# What is minimum RAM for running plutus-playground-server on Ubuntu VirtualBox?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, nix

I am facing this issues when running

```
$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.server
> error: 1 dependencies of derivation
> '/nix/store/39qxl421bhkzks2zrra7vy3yl6qqhsib-zlib-lib-zlib-0.6.2.3-config.drv'
> failed to build
```

It is probably RAM size issue. What is minimum RAM for running plutus-playground-server on Ubuntu VirtualBox?

Comment: I would be surprised if it worked in less that 8G of RAM. Having a decent amount of swap would not hurt either.

Comment: I increased to 10GB fo Virtual Box and `$nix-build -A plutus-playground.server` run successfully. Swap set to 2GB in VM

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: This question could be improved and is not generating good quality answers, please read [answer] and the relevant pinned messages in [help] if you are going to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

As all answers, it depends on your setup. Currently I run the plutus-playground-server setup on a VM with 8gb of ram available (but the playground only uses 1gb of that space). The thing to consider and optimize is the way you run you VM. I run my VM with the libvirt stack (this hypervisor runs near native hardware speeds, very lightweigth). Also I do not render a DE on my VM. I just SSH into the VM and only use the terminal, this also saves a lot of ram usage. So I guess that 2gb will suffice bare minimum (I have not tested this).

a good guide for this hypervisor: https://octetz.com/docs/2020/2020-05-06-linux-hypervisor-setup/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen, that my setup needs around 12GB. Maybe you can optimize it more, but for me it was around 12GB.